# Installed npm module is not visible

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I have installed the module in my project, but it does not found. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Are you using systemjs?

Comment: restart all the things

Comment: please include more details in your question, which technologies you are using and all that

Answer (score 0):

I have found the resolution. In package.json for the version I removed char '^' and reinstall all packages with 'npm install'.

"angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.4" ==> "angular2-infinite-scroll": "0.3.4"

I think the problem was that the package was installed "0.3.43", but the system was looking for "0.3.4". Am I right?